# Get distinct vector of vector with count

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, c++14

What is the best way to return only the unique element with the counts from vector of vectors?

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>> vec_vec{{a,a,b,c},{a,c,c}};
```

The results should be :

```
{a, b, c} // This is the vector that contains the unique items.
{3, 1, 3} //a exists three times, b only one time, and c is three times.
```

To solve this I use the following:

1- Copy all the items in the vector of vector to single vector, so the output will be:

```
vec_vec{{a,a,b,c},{a,c,c}} -> vec{a,a,b,c,a,c,c}
```

2- Now I'm dealing with a single vector (not vector of vector), so it's much easier to sort, get the unique items and them (I may use the code [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector) and [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093423/easier-way-to-count-identical-strings-in-a-vector))

Is converting the vector of vector to one vector is a good idea? Any better solution?

Can we find better way with less complexity comparing with the current way (c++11, c++14)?

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my mind:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> counters;
for(auto const& inner : vec_vec)
  for(auto const& v : inner)
    counters[v]++;

for(auto const& cnt : counters)
  std::cout << cnt.first << " appears " << cnt.second << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use hash maps.

```
std::unordered_map<string, int> result;
for (const auto& x : vec_vec) 
  for (const string& y : x)
     result[y]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `map` as "tally" structure:

```
std::map<string, unsigned int> tally;
for(auto subvector : vector) {  // subvector is std::vector<std::string>
  for(auto item : subvector) {  // item is a std::string
    ++tally[item];
  }
}
```

If you insist on having the result as two parallel vectors (but why would you?) simply construct them from the map:

```
std::vector<std::string> unique_items;
unique_items.reserve(tally.size());
std::vector<unsigned int> counts;
counts.reserve(tally.size());
for(auto item : tally) {
  unique_items.push_back(item.first);
  counts.push_back(item.second);
}
```

If you don't want the result vector to be sorted, you can use an `unordered_map`, as suggested in other answers.